# vps, memcache, mysql, php5-fpm - slow response

Tags: mysql, linux, memcached, vps, php

I've one site hosted on vps (debian 5.0).
I noticed that after 100 rps(requests per second) memcache(1.4.2) being slow and that's why the site being response very slow.
I use nginx + php5-fpm(php - 5.3.8), use pecl memcache module, mysql 5.1.85.
Also I use apc to cache php opcode.
pecl memcache settings :

> ; configuration for php memcache module
>
> extension=memcache.so
>
> memcache.chunk_size=16384

But also I noticed when I moved memcache functionality to apc, it's still acting weird and mysql being slow (after some requests per second - about 150-200)instead of memcache.
I tried to use also pecl memcached module but that's not fixed problem.

Maybe I reach some vps internal limit ?

Any thought ?

Anyone faced with that problem ?
The main page of the site generated for 80 msec, but when I send 5 simultaneous it's started to render for 180 msec.

Comment: I think this would belong better on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)